# A doubt related to Time Complexity !

Tags: c#, algorithm

Consider the following snippet:

```
for(i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(str[i] == ' ')
    {
        i += 2; // I am just incrementing it by 2, so that i can retrieve i+1 
        continue;
    }
    // rest of the code with many similar increments of i 
}
```

Say suppose the loop never turns up into infinity and If I traverse through the loop with many such increments and decrements, I am sure the complexity would not be of order N or N Square. But is there any generalised complexity for such kind of solutions ??

*P.S: I know it`s the worst code, but still wanted to give it a try :-)*

Comment: So we're assuming that `i` is modified in the lower part of the loop as well?

Comment: I can't see your complete code, but I'm pretty sure you can not be sure that the running time is *not* be in `Theta(N)`.

Comment: If the first character in the string is a space, you index out of the bounds of the array. Therefore, your program takes infinitely long to finish the algorithm, as it is forced to abort!

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `i` is a signed integer?  If `i` is unsigned it will never be less than 0.

Comment: Without the "rest of the code," it's impossible to say what this loop will do. As it's currently presented, it's an infinite loop if the string contains the sequence " XX", that is, a space followed by two non-space characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an infinite loop (infinite complexity) if you have a space in your string. Since you are using `continue`, it goes back to `for` and it starts from i+2.

Comment: how this program would run infinite amt of times if the string contains only single space.It would go infinitely only if string is made up of all spaces.Also if i is an int or long it would soon become negative after reaching its max value.

Comment: This is a reverse for loop, `i` starts from maximum and its value decrements. So when it hits a space, `i` is incremented so loop has to start from 2 positions above and it will hit the same space... so **it can never get passed the first space.**

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that `str` does not change over the course of this traversal.

You are traversing `str` backwards and when you hit a space you move the index forward by one i.e. it would hit the space again in the next decrement and then move it forward again i.e. your claim that the loop is not infinite, does not seem valid.

Answer (score 1):

If no mutable state affects the path taken by `i`, then either you go into an infinite loop, or you exit the loop in `n` or less steps.  In the latter case, the worst case performance will be `O(N)`.

If the loop mutates some other state, and that state affects the path, then it is impossible to predict the complexity without understanding the state and the mutation process.

(As written, the code will go into an infinite loop ... unless the section at the end of the loop does something to prevent it.)